# How to get 2nd thing out of every line using python and file parsing

Tags: python, file, parsing

i'm trying to parse through a file with structure:

```
0   rs41362547  MT  10044
1   rs28358280  MT  10550
...
```

and so forth, where i want the second thing in each line to be put into an array. I know it should be pretty easy, but after a lot of searching, I'm still lost. I'm really new to python, what would be the script to do this?

THanks!

Comment: have a look at [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function

Answer (score 4):

You can split the lines using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
with open('file.txt') as infile:
    result = []
    for line in infile: #loop through the lines
        data = line.split(None, 2)[1] #split, get the second column
        result.append(data) #append it to our results
        print data #Just confirming
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as myfile:       # Open the file
    data = []                               # Make a list to hold the data
    for line in myfile:                     # Loop through the lines in the file
        data.append(line.split(None, 2)[1]) # Get the data and add it to the list
print (data)                                # Print the finished list
```

The important parts here are:

1. [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which breaks up the lines based on whitespace.
2. The [with-statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), which auto-closes the file for you when done.

---

Note that you could also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('/path/to/file') as myfile:
    data = [line.split(None, 2)[1] for line in myfile]
print (data)
```

Comment: @user3078700 - Happy to have helped!  Please don't forget to accept my answer (click the check) to let people know that this problem is solved.